# why does this indentation error is arising?

Tags: python, indentation, plotly-python

I am using the following code but I am facing indentation error while trying to run it.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
def plot_cases_for _country (country):
labels = ['confirmed' , 'death']
colors = ['blue' , 'red']
mode_size  = [ 6,8]
line_size = [4,5]

df_list = [confirmed_df , death_df]

fig = go.Figure()
    for i , df  in enumerate(df_list):
           if  country =='World' or country == 'world' :
                x_data = np.array(list(df.iloc[: , 5:].columns))
                y_data = np.sum(np.asarray(df.iloc[: , 5:]) ,axis = 0)


                else:
                x_data = np.array(list(df.iloc[: , 5:].columns))
                y_data = np.sum(np.asarray(df[df['country']==country].iloc[: , 5:]) ,axis = 0)

            fig.add_trace(go.scatter(x = x _data, y = y_data , mode ='lines +markers',
                                        name = labels[i]
                                        line  = dict(color=colors[i] , width = line_size[i] ) ,
                                        connectgaps = True ,
                                        text = "Total" + str(labels[i]) + " :" + str(y_data[-1])

                                        ))

            fig.show( )



            plot_cases_for_country('us')
```

how to solve the following error ?

```
File "<tokenize>", line 21
    fig.add_trace(go.scatter(x = x _data, y = y_data , mode ='lines +markers',
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

kindly help to find out

Comment: Lines 12, 17, 21, 29, 33 all need the same indentation.

Comment: In Python indentation is crucial. You have several places where this is a problem. You can only increase indentation when the previous line started a new block, like with `if`, `else`, `elif`, `while`, `for`, `def`, `class`, ...